# How to add a new column by aggregating values from multiple columns in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I have an excel file that I imported in SSIS and want to transfer it to SQL server as a new table in the destination DB, the table is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to calculate the Average of Scores for each player as new column as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried to accomplish this, but I couldn't success.

Comment: Rather let the database handle the transformation as your database will most likely do it faster than letting SSIS do it, insert your data into your destination but leave average column as `NULL`, write an `UPDATE` sql or `STORED PROCEDURE` to update your average column after the load, let SSIS call the update after doing the load

Comment: Smart suggestion but I have a read only to DB, I can't create a PROCEDURE

Comment: I don't mean a `STORED PROCEDURE` on the source database, the destination database where you are inserting the records, if you can `INSERT` then you should be able to `UPDATE` too?. Run your process and insert all the data but leave the AVERAGE column empty then after the insert run an `UPDATE` statement on the inserted data to calculate and populate the AVERAGE

Comment: @Ockert yes that's work, I was able to get the average with update query after the data flow, thank you

Comment: cool, I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather let the database handle the transformation as your database will most likely do it faster than letting SSIS do it, insert your data into your destination but leave average column as `NULL`, write an `UPDATE` sql or `STORED PROCEDURE` to update your average column after the load, let SSIS call the update after doing the load

[image: Populate]